# Is it good practice to use subcollections in Firestore underneath non-existent documents?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Subcollections in Firestore must reference a document within a collection. If this document is ever deleted, its subcollections remain. However, is it good practice to create subcollections underneath documents that never exist (never have existed, never will exist)? Is there any vulnerability in this pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really make any difference - it is neither "good" nor "bad".  Do whatever suits your application.  The data in subcollections can be queried regardless if the parent document exists or not, and creating or deleting that parent document doesn't affect the subcollection in any way.